# Scrape required information from website - Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to **scrape** "Product Dimensions" information which is "102.87 x 40.64 x 11.43 cm; 16.33 Kilograms" using Beautifulsoup - below is the soup text

Input:
[image]

Output:

```
{'Product Dimensions': '102.87 x 40.64 x 11.43 cm; 16.33 Kilograms'}
```

Comment: Could you also provide a url of the website and some of your code please. It will help to clarify, if there are also other approaches. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
el = soup.find('span', {'class': 'a-text-bold'})
el_k = el.text.replace(':', "").encode('ascii', 'ignore').strip().decode('utf-8')
el_v = el.find_next().text
d = {el_k:el_v}
```